# angularJS get inner elements of directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Short overview:

i need to do autofocus, with the help of it i could after click on enter key go to the next input and with key - seems that i done: but now i try to get input's attribute, as i'm new to angularjs i want to know: how to do it in the best way?

```
<div modal-focus>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="on-input" name="name" modal-focus-order="1"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" class="on-input" name="jobTitle" modal-focus-order="2"/>
    </div>  
</div>
```

how with this code in modal-focus directive link function:

```
angular.element('.on-input').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log(element.find(this)); // how to get modal-focus-order value like 1 or two?
});

element.bind("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.which === 13) {
    /* some magic is here */
  }
});
```

i could get `modal-focus-order` value when i click on input?

Comment: Check out `event.target` instead of `this`

Comment: @below9k also how to fetch there field?

Comment: Angular has $scope and namespacing for templating which you should probably read (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/) cause that's the hole point of angularjs - otherwise I would suggest using jQuery personally. `event.target.value` is the most direct way to get the value for you without frameworks.

Comment: i mean value of some inner directive attribute

Answer (score 0):

I created a plunker that show solution. Check the link .It logs my-directive="VALUE" ' s value

http://plnkr.co/edit/Nc5x25cqZbL64aZxQD96?p=preview

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <span my-directive='123456'></span>
  </body>

</html>





var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.clickme=function(){
    alert('clicked');


    console.log($('#xx').attr('my-directive'));
  }
});


app.directive('myDirective',function(){

  return {
      restrict:'AE',
      replace: true,
      template: function(scope,elem, attr) {
        var newElem = '<input id="xx" type="button" ng-click="clickme()" value="click on me" />';
        return newElem;
      }
    };


})
```

Comment: I edited my plunkr and  You my friend  can use that  : **angular.element(document.querySelector( '#xx' ) ).attr('my-directive')**